# Comparing coefficients between 2 groups in a linear probability model with categorical variable. Using an interaction doesn't seem viable

Tags: probability, linear, regression-coefficients

I am using a linear probability model to look at the effect of competitiveness on gambling, using competitive sport as a proxy to measure competitiveness. My dependent variable is a dummy variable, which takes the value 1 if someone gambled in the past 12 months and 0 otherwise. My independent variable is a categorical variable, taking the value 1 if someone took part in competitive sport, 2 if they took part in only fitness-based physical activity and 0 if they did not undertake any physical activity at all. I also have a range of control variables.

I want to look at whether the effect of participating in competitive sport on gambling varies by age. Looking at past posts on this forum, I've seen that the normally suggested method would be to interact age with competitive sport. However, in my dataset, the age variable ranges from 16-75, so I think that an interaction would probably not be a good idea in this case because the change in the competitive sport effect for a 1 year increase in age is likely to be very small. Therefore, I thought of running two separate regressions: one for people aged over 45 and one for people aged under 45. I have almost 4,500 observations for each subgroup so sample size should not be a problem.

My main interest is to determine whether the competitive sport coefficient is significantly different between the two age groups. I have seen that the use of the suest command has been suggested on this forum previously. I'm not sure whether this would work in my case because my independent variable is a categorical variable? I'm also not sure whether I should be testing for equality of all the coefficients or the equality of only the competitive sport coefficients between the two regressions?

I would be really grateful for any help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: To me this question is quite clear so I recommend it be kept open.

Comment: To counter your "not a good idea" reasoning (2nd paragraph):  1) There is no reason why you must limit yourself to an effect that corresponds with a single year's difference in age.  2) Have you thought about assessing the change in the age effect at different levels of physical activity?

Comment: If your coefficients are uncomfortably small then I would divide age by ten or twenty to get them back into a printable range. Is there any reason why that did not work for you?